# Proof of $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{P - 1} {{i^{P - 2}}} \equiv 0\pmod{P^2}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $P$ be  prime greater than 3. Let $S_2(N,M)$ be the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Is this proof correct？Is it a known formula？
$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{P - 1} {{i^{P - 2}}}  + {P^{P - 2}} = \sum\limits_{g = 0}^{P - 2}g! {{S_2}} (P - 1,g + 1)\binom P{g+1} = \sum\limits_{g = 1}^{P - 1} (g-1)!{{S_2}} (P - 1,g)\binom P g $$
$$ = P\sum\limits_{g = 1}^{P - 1} {{{g!{S_2}(P - 1,g)} \over {{g^2}}}} \binom{P-1}{g-1}$$
$$g!{S_2}(P - 1,g) \equiv {( - 1)^g}\pmod P,\binom{P-1}{g-1} \equiv {( - 1)^g}\pmod P$$
$${1 \over P}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^P {{i^{P - 2}}}  \equiv \sum\limits_{g = 1}^{P - 1} {{1 \over {{g^2}}}}  \equiv \sum\limits_{g = 1}^{P- 1} {{g^2}}  \equiv 0\pmod{P}$$

Comment: What is the meaning of the function $S_2$? Hard to say anything without knowing that. Also, what is the connection between the first formula and the one in the title?

Comment: Use `\binom n k` to typeset a binomial coefficient $\binom n k$.

Comment: Check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/183954/11619).

Comment: S_2 is the stirling number of the second kind.
P^(p-2) is clearly divisible by p^2.Change the sum to [1,P],make it easier to calculate.

Comment: Wolstenholme's theorem is different from this one.

Comment: [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Please try and make it easier for people you ask for help by adding links. Anyway, I'm not familiar enough with the Stirling numbers to decide whether your first identity is correct, so I'm leaving this for someone else.

Comment: In the first line, are $p$ and $P$ the same thing?

Comment: Yes ,they are same thing.

Comment: Then please edit your post to type them everywhere the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is correct and it is known. See for example *[On Congruences Involving Bernoulli Numbers and the Quotients of Fermat and Wilson](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968791)* by Emma Lehmer. This congruence can be obtained in a more direct way by using the [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula):
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{P} {{i^{P - 2}}}=\frac{1}{P-1}\sum _{k=0}^{P-2}\binom{P-1}{ k}B_{k}P^{P-1-k}\equiv \frac{1}{P-1}B_{P-2}P=0 \pmod{P^2}$$
where the [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) $B_{P-2}$ is zero because $P-2$ is and odd number greater than $1$.