# Wolstenholme Theorem is just a special case.A large number of congruences $\pmod {P^2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$P$ is prime,$P$>3.Wolstenholme Theorem is:

$$(P - 1)!\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{P - 1} {\frac{1}{n}}  = \sum\limits_{0 < {K_i},{K_j} < P,{K_i} \ne {K_j}} {{K_1}} {K_2}...{K_{P - 2}} \equiv 0\pmod {P^2} \ \ \ (1)$$
[There](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739246/proof-of-sum-limits-i-1p-1-ip-2-equiv-0-pmodp2) has another congruence:
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{P - 1} {{n^{P - 2}}}  \equiv 0\pmod {P^2}\ \ \ (2)$$
They are two extremes.In fact,there have:
$${\sum\limits_{0 < {K_i},{K_j} < P,{K_i} \ne {K_j}} {{K_1}} ^{{C_1}}}{K_2}^{{C_2}}...{K_q}^{Cq} \equiv 0\pmod {P^2},{C_1} + {C_2} + ... + {C_q} = P - 2,{C_i} > 0$$
The proof should use:
$${\sum\limits_{0 < {K_i},{K_j} < P,{K_i} \ne {K_j}} {{K_1}} ^{{C_1}}}{K_2}^{{C_2}}...{K_q}^{Cq} \equiv 0\pmod P,{C_1} + {C_2} + ... + {C_q} < P - 1,{C_i} > 0\ \ \ (3)$$
If $X \pmod {P^2}$ and $X+Y \pmod {P^2}$ then $Y \pmod {P^2}$.The Sum has symmetry.
For $∑AB^{P-3}$,pair each product $AB^{P-3}$ with another $(P-A)B^{P-3}$ to $PB^{P-3}$,
$(P-A)B^{P-3}∈∑AB^{P-3} or ∑B^{P-2}$.
$∑(Paired\ Prodcuts)=x∑AB^{P-3}+y∑B^{P-2}=zP∑B^{P-3},0<x,y<P$
$(2)\to y∑B^{P-2}\equiv 0\pmod {P^2} $;$(3)\to P∑B^{P-3}\equiv 0\pmod {P^2} $.
So $∑AB^{P-3}\equiv 0\pmod {P^2} $
And so on...
$$2\left( {{1^2}} \right) + 3\left( {{1^2} + {2^2}} \right) + 4\left( {{1^2} + {2^2} + {3^2}} \right) + {2^2}\left( 1 \right) + {\text{ }}{3^2}\left( {1 + 2} \right) + {4^2}\left( {1 + 2 + 3} \right) = 200 \equiv 0\pmod {25}$$

Any ideas?